# Images Don't Load in Xcode iOS emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hi I am trying to develop a webapp, and when I run my React Native code in the Xcode iOS emulator, none of my static images (located in a 'src/assets' folder) load. My syntax of loading Images is correct (i.e. I have a source tag and even specified width and hieght).

Why don't images load in my iOS emulator?
Anyone else run into this issue?

I have Xcode 12 and react-native 0.61.5. My emulator is running iOS 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced similar issue, fixed after updating react native version to 0.63.2

Comment: Yup, I fixed it because the app I was working on was not compatible with iOS 14 emulator :/.